# Saving the entire state (hibernate) of Ubuntu into a file and select it for restore?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hibernate, suspend

I wanted to know if it's possible to simulate the hibernate process of Ubuntu to save the entire state session into a file. Then to select which one to restore ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, you can't.

When a system hibernates, it saves the contents of RAM into a swap file (as in Windows) or to a swap partition (as in Linux).  Ubuntu *could* hibernate to a swap *file*.

**However**, you simply cannot have two hibernated states at the same time.  When you hibernate, the RAM references little system writes that are going on as well as hard drive contents, etc.  If you resume that state with those things changed, you'll screw up your system.  Operating systems delete the hibernation data after resuming to prevent this.

Comment: Oh this is so disappointing. I was googling this thinking I just had a brilliant idea and wondering why nobody was doing it... use case would be: preserve state of computer when everything is setup just the way I like with 4 windows on 18 workspaces each on 3 différent screens, code editor open 5 times, all the tabs in the chromes, 1278 terminals... well, my good productive mess after a few hours of work and THEN for some stupid reason (like, I decided to try a new display manager) I have to log out or reboot and loose all this organization work. Seriously breaks the flow.